# VueJS re-compile HTML in an inline-template component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-table

I've wrapped bootstrapTable (https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) into a directive, like this:

```
Vue.directive('bootstraptable', {
    priority: 1000,

    params: ['url', 'resource-name'],

    bind: function () {

        var _self = this;

        $(this.el)
            .bootstrapTable({
                pagination: true,
                pageSize: 15,
                pageList: [],
                sidePagination: 'server',
                url: this.params.url,
                queryParams: function (params) {
                    return params;
                },
                cookie: true,
                cookieExpire: '24h',
                cookieIdTable: this.params.resourceName + '-table',
                locale: 'it-IT'
            }).on('load-success.bs.table', function (e, data) {

                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                _self.vm.$compile(_self.vm.$el);
            });
    },
    update: function (value) {
        $(this.el).val(value)
    },
    unbind: function () {
        $(this.el).off().bootstrapTable('destroy')
    }
});
```

The JSON returned from the server contains a button with a v-on directive so I have to recompile the injected HTML rows to have the button directives properly working.
Anyway, it seems that the following code isn't working:

`_self.vm.$compile(_self.vm.$el);`

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried `$mount` ?

Comment: The component is already mounted, infact, if I call `$mount` this is what I get: `[Vue warn]: $mount() should be called only once.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $compile method needs to be called on the elements that have to be compiled, not on the vm root element.

I changed the line:

```
_self.vm.$compile(_self.vm.$el);
```

with:

```
            _.each($('[recompile]'), function(el){
                _self.vm.$compile(el);
            });
```

and added the attribute "recompile" to all the HTML elements that need to be recompiled.

This seems to be working as expected, do not hesitate to answer if there is a more conventional way to do that.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank u a lot.

In my case:
`var th = this;
    _.each($('[recompile=true]'), function(el){
        th.$compile(el);
        $(el).removeAttr('recompile');
    });`