# VueJs manipulate inline template and reinitialize it

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

this question is similar to [VueJS re-compile HTML in an inline-template component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087195/vuejs-re-compile-html-in-an-inline-template-component) and also to [How to make Vue js directive working in an appended html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546370/how-to-make-vue-js-directive-working-in-an-appended-html-element)

Unfortunately the solution in that question can't be used anymore for the current VueJS implementation as `$compile` was removed.

My use case is the following:

I have to use third party code which manipulates the page and fires an event afterwards. Now after that event was fired I would like to let VueJS know that it should reinitialize the current DOM.

(The third party which is written in pure javascript allows an user to add new widgets to a page)

https://jsfiddle.net/5y8c0u2k/

HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <my-input inline-template>
  <div class="wrapper">
  My inline template<br>
  <input v-model="value">
  <my-element inline-template :value="value">
    <button v-text="value" @click="click"></button>
  </my-element>
  </div>
    </my-input>
</div>
```

Javascript - VueJS 2.2

```
Vue.component('my-input', {
    data() {
        return {
            value: 1000
        };
    }
});

Vue.component('my-element', {
    props: {
        value: String
    },
    methods: {
        click() {
            console.log('Clicked the button');
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});

// Pseudo code
setInterval(() => {
  // Third party library adds html:
  var newContent = document.createElement('div');
  newContent.innerHTML = `<my-element inline-template :value="value">
     <button v-text="value" @click="click"></button>
  </my-element>`;   document.querySelector('.wrapper').appendChild(newContent)

   //      
   // How would I now reinialize the app or
   // the wrapping component to use the click handler and value?
   //

}, 5000)
```

Comment: Can the new code show up absolutely anywhere on the page?

Comment: Yes there are multiple locations which are generated dynamically. I found a solution but it feels more like a hack: https://jsfiddle.net/9ukmy0k0/

Comment: The hackiness is unavoidable: you're violating the contract with Vue that it will control the DOM.

Comment: That's the pain during large projects and existing solutions - you can't get in control of everything :(

Comment: Do you want the current state of the of `my-input` shared by the `my-element`s? This might be less hacky.  https://jsfiddle.net/9ukmy0k0/2/

Comment: No I am looking for a generic solution and tried to reduce it to a simple example

Answer (score 3):

After further investigation I reached out to the VueJs team and got the [feedback](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5621) that the following approach could be a valid solution:

```
/**
 * Content change handler
 */
function handleContentChange() {
  const inlineTemplates = document.querySelector('[inline-template]');
  for (var inlineTemplate of inlineTemplates) {
    processNewElement(inlineTemplate);
  }
}


/**
 * Tell vue to initialize a new element
 */
function processNewElement(element) {
  const vue = getClosestVueInstance(element);
  new Vue({
    el: element,
    data: vue.$data
  });
}

/**
 * Returns the __vue__ instance of the next element up the dom tree
 */
function getClosestVueInstance(element) {
  if (element) {
    return element.__vue__ || getClosestVueInstance(element.parentElement);
  }
}
```

You can try it in the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vxwr34o/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Generally when I hear questions like this, they seem to always be resolved by using some of Vue's more intimate and obscured inner beauty :)

I have used quite a few third party libs that 'insist on owning the data', which they use to modify the DOM - but if you can use these events, you can proxy the changes to a Vue owned object - or, if you can't have a vue-owned object, you can observe an independent data structure through computed properties.

```
window.someObjectINeedtoObserve = {...}

yourLib.on('someEvent', (data) => {
  // affect someObjectINeedtoObserve...
})

new Vue ({
  // ...
  computed: {
    myObject () {
      // object now observed and bound and the dom will react to changes
      return window.someObjectINeedtoObserve 
    }
  }
})
```

If you could clarify the use case and libraries, we might be able to help more.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you can articulate the overall functional requirement, you might get an easer more concise answer than your 'workaround' above - in my 3 years of working with Vue, I've never had to do such. I really think the answer might be in taking a different approach of linking the data, the dom, the vue instance and your 3rd party lib.

Comment: The key problem is that we are not building only a simple app but try to use Vue together with a CMS