# Loading dynamic content inside a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `tabs` component with a template of that kind:

```html
<div class="tabnav">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="tab in tabs" v-text="tab.title"></li>
  </ul>
  <div v-for="tab in tabs" v-html="tab.content"></div>
</div>
```

New tabs will be added on-demand through an Ajax request. I wonder how I can have my content (tab.content) to be automatically mounted. The new tabs are created but if I have components in this content, they are not *Vueified*.

What is the right approach to get this dynamic content integrated in my existing component with its specific set of methods, data, etc...?

If the only solution is to make of each content a distinct component itself, must it be named? If not, how do I integrate it in the tab?

Comment: You might want to check out [Async components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components)

Comment: If your Ajax request must modify the DOM rather than feeding you data to put into your Vue, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43829352/392102).  It would be far better to get data rather than DOM elements.